# JavaScript Regex: remember a match without getting `undefined` results

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting this:

```
var string = "I am a string with <span class='foo'>tags and stuff</span> as well as words";
return string.split(/(<.*?>)|\s/g);
```

The goal is to split along every space `\s`, as well as on any tags `(<.*?>)`. The thing is, I want to remember any tag matches, so I put them in parenthesis. Problem is, the results also remember every section of the string that *doesn't* have a tag, resulting in:

```
["I", undefined, "am", undefined, "a", undefined, "string", undefined, "with", undefined, "", "<span class='foo'>", "tags", undefined, "and", undefined, "stuff", "</span>", "", undefined, "as", undefined, "well", undefined, "as", undefined, "words"]
```

Well, that won't work. Anyone know of a way to conditionally remember only when the tag is actually present?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do string.split() results include undefined?](/q/20693388/90527)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to have the matches only included when the match group is realised. But you could do this without `split`:

```
return string.match(/<.*?>|[^<\s]+/g);
```

```js
var string = "I am a string with <span class='foo'>tags and stuff</span> as well as words";
var result = string.match(/<.*?>|[^<\s]+/g);
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend",
  JSON.stringify(result).replace(/</g, "&lt;")
);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You never use the `g` flag with `split`. Remove it.

```js
var string = "I am a string with <span class='foo'>tags and stuff</span> as well as words";
var result = string.split(/(<.*?>)|\s/);
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend",
  JSON.stringify(result).replace(/</g, "&lt;")
);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

As for the `undefined`s (they show as `null`s in the above because I did `JSON.stringify` on output), that's by design: When you include a capture group in the `split` regex, it inserts the capture group values into the array you get back. If you don't want that, `split` isn't the right tool for the job; you may want `String#match` or `RegExp#exec` instead (in which case, you would want the `g` flag again).

Alternately, I suppose, you could filter them out:

```js
var string = "I am a string with <span class='foo'>tags and stuff</span> as well as words";
var result = string.split(/(<.*?>)|\s/).filter(function(entry) {
  return !!entry;
});
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend",
  JSON.stringify(result).replace(/</g, "&lt;")
);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```